# No migrations to apply while in makemigrations migrations are shown

Tags: python, django, model, django-migrations

Even When there are migrations to apply when making the command migrate it shows no migrations to apply
[image: Even When there are migrations to apply when making the command migrate it shows no migrations to apply]

Comment: Please post your code and output as text! Screenshots of text are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ```python manage.py migrate company```

Comment: Did you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your project to get all modules form django to your project.

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the migrations cache and running makemigrations and migrate again.
Thanks anyways